# Shell Script Not Starting Service

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a very basic shell script that checks for a given service, and then query the service to find out whether service is running or not. If service not running it tries to restart the service. But it is not working. When I stop the service. It never enters in the "if" section even though, service is not running. Is the exit status "0" I check the output in the terminal and is not "0" but still will not go into the "if" section. What am I missing? Any help appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash
#checking for apache

service="sshd"

whie [ 1 ]
do
    ps -e | grep $service
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        service ssh start
    fi
    sleep 3
done
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste your script or did you re-type it? Avoid re-typing as you may introduce typos like `whie` that confuse the question.

Comment: Checking for apache or sshd?

Comment: 1. `ps -e | grep $service` is not sufficiently robust to check if a service is running. What is wrong with checking the output of `service $service status`? 2. `service ssh start` will never do anything.

Comment: Typo: `whie` should be `while`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `service $service start`?

Comment: A good process supervision system ([`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/), [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [`launchd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd), [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), ...) will do all the hard work for you, **including** restarting a service if it ever fails. If you need to run `service ssh start` in a loop, either (1) your init system hasn't been told to restart `sshd` when it fails; (2) you're using something awful and ancient like SysV init scripts (don't!), or (3) something is very, *very* wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that something needs to actually *start* your shell script for it to run, and that the script can be killed by an OOM / a stray signal / etc -- but a proper init system will be started by the kernel as PID 1 (or itself started/supervised by PID 1), and will be up as long as anything else on the system is (if PID 1 dies, that's a kernel panic).

Answer (score 0):

[Process management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) is a complex business, but can also be made very simple. In your case, all you need is a script to make sure the service is started and keeps running, which can be done by figuring out which command `/etc/init.d/sshd` actually runs and then plugging that into this script:

```
while true
do
    [command from /etc/init.d/sshd]
done
```

PS: As [@CharlesDuffy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412190/shell-script-not-starting-service#comment89799487_51414018), you'll want to first check whether the process daemonizes (runs in the background, returning immediately). If it does you'll have to modify the command so that doesn't happen.

Comment: It's perhaps important to clarify that this only works if the command doesn't try to self-daemonize. BTW, from http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html#sshd, it looks like the command in question should be `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -e`

Comment: The question appears `systemd` related, not one using the old SysV init scripts. As an additional note, as written in the question, if there is a problem preventing `sshd` from starting (e.g. incorrect permission, etc..), an endless loop results. There should be some sane limit on the number of tries or the amount of time spent attempting to start the service (or launch the init script)